# Why does Itertool Permutations recurse till recursionError in def function?

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

I'm just wondering why I'm getting the error: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
When trying:

```
def permutations(string):
    permlist = permutations(string)
    combolist = []


    for perm in list(permlist): 
        if ''.join(perm) not in combolist:
            combolist.append(''.join(perm))

    print(f"{combolist}")
```

I get this error:

```
permlist = permutations(string)
  [Previous line repeated 996 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

However, when I try it outside of a def, it works no problem:

```
 
permlist = permutations('abba')
combolist = []
 
 
for perm in list(permlist): 
    if ''.join(perm) not in combolist:
        combolist.append(''.join(perm))
 
print(f"{combolist}")
 

output:

['abba', 'abab', 'aabb', 'baba', 'baab', 'bbaa']
```

I'm not very familiar with itertools or permutations or anything, but I'm just wondering why the permutation is recurring in a def, is there any way to possibly run the permutation once in the def, when executing the for loop afterwards or something?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The very first line of `permutations` itself calls `permutations` with the exact same parameters, that's an infinite loop. Call your function something else or don't use `from itertools import *` and instead use `import itertools` and `itertools.permutations`

Comment: Wow!, I can't believe it was this simple.. Thanks Nick! :)

Comment: @Nick we need another Nick to vtc...

Comment: @Nick Blast, we need to recruit to our ranks

Comment: @Nick, I have no idea who I summoned, however the 1st Nick on this page should post their comment as a solution.

Comment: @JosephWood you pinged the right Nick, however I try not to answer duplicates, I've already voted to close as such and OP is happy they got the solution, so it's win-win